# Add class to <img> only when its parentNode (div) has a certain className? - No jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

To evaluate on my question, I need a way in Vanilla JavaScript to add a class to an `img` tag, that executes depending on what class of div that `img` tag is child to **- I need to add a `class` to an `img` if its `parentNode` contains "*box*."**

This is a simplified example of my code:

```
<div class="example first">
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box">
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box">
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>




var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
if (div[i].classList.value.indexOf("example") > -1){
    div[i].classList.add("style-1");

if (div[i].classList.value.indexOf("box") > -1){
    div[i].classList.add("style-2");
    div[i].classList.remove("style-1");

for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
    img[i].classList.add("img-class");
     }
   }
 }
}
```

This code sort of provides the desired outcome, however, it applies `img-class` to the `classList` of ALL `img` tags, even though the parent div does not contain `box` in their `classList`; e.g. `img-class` is also applied to the div with class `example first`.

It also removes the classes added to the `classList` of the divs following the first div that contains `example box` in their `classList`.

EXAMPLE:

```
<div class="example first style-1">
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img class="img-class" src="./img/sample.png" /> /* UNWANTED CLASS APPLIED */
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box style-2">
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img class="img-class" src="./img/sample.png" />
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box"> /* NO CLASS APPLIED WHEN SHOULD BE */
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img class="img-class" src="./img/sample.png" />
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>
```

while the desired outcome is:

```
<div class="example first style-1">
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" /> /*NO CLASS APPLIED*/
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box style-2">
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img class="img-class" src="./img/sample.png" />
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box style-2"> /* STYLE APPLIED */
 <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img class="img-class" src="./img/sample.png" />
 <p>sample text</p>
</div>
```

I've also tried the following JavaScript to no prevail:

```
var parentNodeImg = img.parentNode;
if (parentNodeImg.classList.value.indexOf("box") > -1){
  img.classList.add("img-class");
}
```

Thanks in advance! I know there's a bit here, I've tried to refine it as much as I can.

Comment: you can also try `el.classList.contains('box')`

Comment: @Phiter Thank you, thats an easy alternative to value.indexOf() !

Comment: What do you need this class for in the first place? (If you just want to format images inside such a box element differently from other images, that would not need JavaScript at all, just some knowledge of CSS selectors.)

Comment: @Cbroe I understand CSS, just working on making elements flow at the moment using HTML classes/tags/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to query only those `img` tags which are in a div with the class `box` and add the class to only those elements

```js
var selectedImgTags = document.querySelectorAll('.box > img');

selectedImgTags.forEach(function(el) {
  el.className += ' magic';
})
```

```css
/* Adding this to illustrate the difference visually in the output */
.magic {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example first">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do by applying the following code in javascript

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
boxes.map(function(box){
var img = box.querySelector("img");
img.classList.add("img-class");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing a bit with your code,
Here is a working snippet:
(I added CSS for visibility)

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var i, j, img;

for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  if (div[i].classList.contains("example")) {
    div[i].classList.add("style-1");

    if (div[i].classList.contains('box')) {
      div[i].classList.add("style-2");
      div[i].classList.remove("style-1");
      
      img = div[i].getElementsByTagName("img");
      for (j = 0; j < img.length; j++) {
        img[j].classList.add("img-class");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.style-1 {
  background: #aaa;
}

.style-2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.img-class{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example first">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="./img/sample.png" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>
```

I tried not altering much your code but used `contains()` to check if a class is present.

Note that you were using the variable `i` in the second loop, I replaced it using `j` because it caused some malfunctioning.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked in fixing the issue with div classes not appearing in the third div, however this still allocates the "img-class" to the div with class "example first"?

Comment: @KAindex You're right. I modified it right now. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**`classList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of commonly used `className.split(' ')`

Below you can see a working example in action:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

images.forEach(img => {
  var clss = img.parentNode.classList;
  
  clss.forEach(cls => {
    if (cls == 'box') {
      img.classList.add('img-class');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.img-class {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example first style-1">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box style-2">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="example box">
  <h2><a>sample text</a></h2>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
  <p>sample text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through every single div you can iterate only through divs with the class you want:

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].tagName === 'DIV') {/* Get your imgs and add class to them */}
}
```

You can get all img children of a given div with:

```
let imgs = divElement.getElementsByTagName('img');
```